# List of scripts

Tags: list, unity-game-engine

In Unity can I have a list of scripts? I have a ModeController that is supposed to enable and disable other scripts during run time. Problem is that the amount of scripts that it handles is increasing and manually enabling and disabling each script is becoming more and more difficult. Here's the code at the moment:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;

public class ModeController : MonoBehaviour {

    public CharacterController characterController;
    public CarController carController;
    public JetpackController jetpackController;
    public WhateverController1 whateverController1;
    public WhateverController2 whateverController2;
    public WhateverController3 whateverController3;
    public WhateverController4 whateverController4;

    void Start(){
        SetMode ();
    }

    public void SetMode(){

        if (mode == "Basic") {

            characterController.enabled = true;
            carController.enabled = false;
            jetpackController.enabled = false;
            whateverController1.enabled = false;
            whateverController2.enabled = false;
            whateverController3.enabled = false;
            whateverController4.enabled = false;

        } else if (mode == "Car") {

            characterController.enabled = false;
            carController.enabled = true;
            jetpackController.enabled = false;
            whateverController1.enabled = false;
            whateverController2.enabled = false;
            whateverController3.enabled = false;
            whateverController4.enabled = false;

        } else if (mode == "Jetpack") {

            characterController.enabled = false;
            carController.enabled = false;
            jetpackController.enabled = true;
            whateverController1.enabled = false;
            whateverController2.enabled = false;
            whateverController3.enabled = false;
            whateverController4.enabled = false;

        } else if (mode == "Whatever1") {

            characterController.enabled = false;
            carController.enabled = false;
            jetpackController.enabled = false;
            whateverController1.enabled = true;
            whateverController2.enabled = false;
            whateverController3.enabled = false;
            whateverController4.enabled = false;

        } else if (mode == "Whatever2") {

            characterController.enabled = false;
            carController.enabled = false;
            jetpackController.enabled = false;
            whateverController1.enabled = false;
            whateverController2.enabled = true;
            whateverController3.enabled = false;
            whateverController4.enabled = false;

        } else if (mode == "Whatever3") {

            characterController.enabled = false;
            carController.enabled = false;
            jetpackController.enabled = false;
            whateverController1.enabled = false;
            whateverController2.enabled = false;
            whateverController3.enabled = true;
            whateverController4.enabled = false;

        } else if (mode == "Whatever4") {

            characterController.enabled = false;
            carController.enabled = false;
            jetpackController.enabled = false;
            whateverController1.enabled = false;
            whateverController2.enabled = false;
            whateverController3.enabled = false;
            whateverController4.enabled = true;
        }

    }

}
```

How could I add all those scripts into one list? Something like:

```
public List<SomeType> scripts = new List<SomeType>();
```

Then I could loop through the list like:

```
foreach(SomeType script in scripts){
    if(something)
        script.enabled = true;
    else 
        script.enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scripts in Unity extend `MonoBehaviour`, so you can do the following

```
public List<MonoBehaviour> Scripts;
```

then you can loop through like you said

```
foreach(var script in Scripts) 
{
    script.enabled = true;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could make a class `Controller` extending `MonoBehaviour` and have your `WhateverController` subclass that. That would be one way to have shared behavior among your controllers.

Comment: Using MonoBehaviour was what I was looking for and it made my life a lot easier. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I initially did something similar when making a game where the player had to be able to switch between different *modes* (combat, construction, etc...).

What ended up working better was using a child object as a container for each group of scripts and then toggle the children as need by setting them as active or inactive. Once you have it setup that way, it is easy to swap the scripts out on the child object as needed.

I could also see using scriptable objects for this scenario. Unity recently had a [live training](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/ability-system-scriptable-objects) session on using scriptable objects that you might be interested in.

Answer (score 0):

`public List<Component> components` can be used to include every kind of scripts.

Adding your scripts to the list isn't that easy though:

1. Select the object containing your list,
2. lock the inspector window,
3. open a second, *unlocked* inspector window (both need to be visible),
4. select an object containing your `WhateverController`,
5. drag the `WhateverContoller` into from the second into the first inspector.
6. repeat from 4 for every script you want to disable

Comment: Note: `enabled` is a property of `MonoBehaviour`. If you use `Component`, you won't be able to access it.